# How many planets does Omicron Persei have?

Tags: star-systems

[Omicron Persei](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omicron_Persei) is a binary star. I did not find information on how many planets it has and if we can actually determine it currently. However, I do know that most stars have planets orbiting around them and so I assume there are such planets.

For those who are interested, Futurama featured the planet Omicron Persei 8 - the 8th planet in that system. I was curious as to if there is an 8th planet.

Comment: You know what they say: men are from Omicron Persei 9, women are from Omicron Persia 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently http://exoplanet.eu/ (which lists more exoplanets than the official NASA archive) lists no known planets of Omicron Persei. So currently we know of none, it is outside of the Kepler field so has no Kepler candidates either.

Though just because none are known that does not mean it has none, it may be that their mass and or orbital plane is such that it is very difficult to identify planets or no one has looked with a suitable instrument.

Comment: Nice answer.   Omicron Persei is listed in Wikipedia as 1,000-1,600 light years away.  There's got to be at least 250,000 stars within 1,000 light years of earth, so, some simple math, I think it's safe to say that less than 1% of stars that distant have been successfully checked for planets, at least, so far.